# Query the title of the page to show posts with matching category in the loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories, query-posts

In the archive page for a custom post type I have this query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'Bordeaux' ) );
```

Then in the loop I have:

```
if ($the_query->have_posts() );
```

Et cetera.

The loop correctly searches my posts and displays all posts with the category 'Bordeaux' on the page.

I would like to alter this query so that instead of searching for the text string 'Bordeaux', it will query the title of the page and search for a category with that name.

This will allow me to have just one .php file for all custom post types, rather than individual ones.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => echo the_title(); );
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to echo the title out.

Try this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => get_the_title() );
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried this but it leads to a "parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'" and breaks the theme. What title does get_the_title get?

Comment: No wait, it worked! There was just a right bracket missing: `$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => get_the_title() ) );`